# What is the best way to use Nuxt fetch on a static site when multiple pages require the same API call

Tags: nuxt.js

I have a static Nuxt site which has multiple pages. Some subset of those pages need to get data from the same API. What is the best way to get data such that it is not fetched when pages that don't need the data are requested and is only fetched once in total for all of the pages that do need it.

A simple example page structure would be:

- / (no API calls)
- /posts (needs user data from API)

  - /posts/1 (needs user data from API)
  - /posts/2 (needs user data from API)
  - /posts/3 (needs user data from API)
  - ...

I'm currently using [fetch for Nuxt >= 2.12](https://nuxtjs.org/api/pages-fetch/) in each page that needs the data. I've been following [this guide](https://nuxtjs.org/blog/understanding-how-fetch-works-in-nuxt-2-12/) closely.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into [Vuex](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/vuex-store/) so you can centralize your data inside the `state` and form your API calls into `actions` which you can then call from every page or component.

Comment: Thanks for your answer however I still need to use fetch in some form so that smart prefetching can extract the API result into its own payload file for fast page transitions